# Receiving error "connection to ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/1/websocket" was interrupted while the page was loading"

Tags: socket.io

Receiving error "connection to ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/1/websocket" was interrupted while the page was loading" How do i rectify this issue? I tried to close the socket connection before opening this new socket connection, however I am still receiving this error. Please Advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can always close the connection beforeonload,

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    socket.close();
});
```

And you can subscribe to onclose of the websocket to handle the error in javascript like this:

```
url = "ws://echo.websocket.org";
    try {
        socket = window['MozWebSocket'] ? new MozWebSocket(url) : new WebSocket(url);
        socket.onopen = function(){
            console.log('Socket is now open.');
        };
        socket.onerror = function (error) {
            console.error('There was an un-identified Web Socket error');
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (message) {
            console.info("Message: %o", message.data);
        };
        socket.onclose = function() {
            console.info( 'Socket is now closed.' );
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Sorry, the web socket at "%s" is un-available', url);
    }

setTimeout(function(){
    socket.send("Hello World");
}, 1000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5aAK/1/

Comment: thank you for your answer. that got me pass the issue I was having. Now I have a different issue where the form is xhr-polling and has been xhr-polling for a while now. When does the xhr-polling stopm and redirect me to where I need to go. The connection times out after the xhr-polling cannot find an open socket.