# Trying to login into application using NodeJS and Sails.JS and receiving server timeout on XHR Polling

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am working on a NodeJS application that uses Sails.JS, that requires a login to get to the dashboard of the application.

Originally I was receiving errors with websockets and used this solution to get past this issue.

[Receiving error "connection to ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/1/websocket" was interrupted while the page was loading"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829363/receiving-error-connection-to-ws-localhost1337-socket-io-1-websocket-was-in)

Now, I have another problem, where the application is xhr-polling and not connecting to anything, and the server timesout and never redirects to the dashboard. This behavior is not happening on some peeers computers, they are able to login successfully. I am trying to figure out why the xhr polling runs and does not redirect me to the dashboard after successful login. Why is this only happening on my machine and not theirs. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.Simply boggles my mind.

Thank You